# Mysql : restore database using batch file

Tags: mysql

Some one please correct the below syntax to restore the mysql backup file using
command prompt.

```
"C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -pmypassword source C:/Program Files/Default Company Name/Setup2/Dump20160805.sql
```

Comment: how about `-e "source /path/to/my/file.sql"`

Comment: @Drew wow.. thanks lot bro

Comment: cool. Something I said actually worked once !

Comment: @Drew i am new to mysql and cmd bro.        can you help me to resolve the this error                                                                       mysql> Dump20160805 < Dump20160805.sql  ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Dump2
0160805 < Dump20160805.sql' at line 1

Comment: if you want to run `mysqldump` do it from the os command line, not inside mysql cmd line. So from within mysql cmd line type quit. Then follow a tutorial about mysqldump

Comment: @Drew i tried something like this also.. "C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql" -u root -ppassword -e Dump20160805 < Dump20160805.sql;   // i received unknow database ; error

Comment: Dump... is not a cmd

Comment: mysqldump is a command line tool

Comment: @Drew true but Dump201* is the file name.. i am not using mysqldump cmd.

Comment: you are executing a sql command that does not exist. That is a 1064. I am out :p

Answer (score 1):

"C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot -pmypassword > C:/Program Files/Default Company Name/Setup2/Dump20160805.sql

Comment: @lzzat raxmatov i want to restore the database

Comment: "C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot database_name -pmypassword < C:/Program Files/Default Company Name/Setup2/Dump20160805.sql

Comment: @Lzzat thansk it worked. is it possible to print the out from mysql.exe to cmd?

Comment: Yeap you need on windows configure environment path to mysql